# Transform single table row + column names into columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple SQL select query that returns the following result (single row):

```
 [0]  [1]  [2]  [3] [13] (column headings)
 5102 4516 31   95  2    (row data)
```

Using SQL, I need to transform this to return two columns (5 rows) that looks like this:

```
[id]  [val]
0     5102
1     4516
2     31
3     95
13    2
```

I expect to be able to do this using pivot or something similar.

SQL query used to produce the first (single row) result:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE KEY = BLAH
```

Comment: Which database engine you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `unpivot` the data

For `SQL Server` use `Cross Apply`. Try this

```
SELECT id,val
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES ([0],'0'),
                           ([1],'1'),
                           ([2],'2'),
                           ([3],'3'),
                           ([13],'13')) cs  (val,id)
```

or Use `Union ALL` to unpivot the data

```
SELECT [0] AS val,'0' AS id
FROM   yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT [1],'1'
FROM   yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT [2],'2'
FROM   yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT [3],'3'
FROM   yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT [13],'13'
FROM   yourtable
```

Comment: Great, that worked!

The trouble with the union all (I'm using MySQL) is that the 'table' is a subquery, so having the same subquery copied 4 or 5 times (or more) is not ideal.

Is there a way to do this without requiring the subquery to be duplicated for each row result?